# How to set string array default value in a Class constructor

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I would like to have a string array in my constructor with the value of "" instead of null but I don't know how to do it.

```
public partial class myClass
{
    public string[,] myGridArray = new string[10, 10];
}
```

I tried to add a method in the Class and call it from the constructor but it's not working.

Comment: Please show us what you tried, and explain why you thought “it's not working”.

Comment: I see neither a method nor a constructor in that code...

Comment: This is completely unclear, you need to a do a bit better with this question and stop making us guess. Yes its hard to write a question, but imagine how hard it is for us to try and decipher them (when they are broad and vague)

Comment: I want the string array values to be set to "" when the constructor is called. Sorry, I don't know how to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `for` loop and the [`Array.GetLength(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength?view=netframework-4.8) Method

> Gets a 32-bit integer that represents the number of elements in the
>   specified dimension of the Array.

```
public partial class myClass
{
   public string[,] myGridArray;

   public myClass()
   {
      myGridArray = new string[10, 10];
      for (var i = 0; i < myGridArray.GetLength(0); i++)
         for (var j = 0; j < myGridArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            myGridArray[i, j] = string.Empty;
   }
}
```